# filtering a collection by its children in linq to entities?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the following query which filters the batches according to whether the items in the batches have a certain issue no. I would like to know if there is more concise way doing this which would look cleaner.

```
neptuneBatches =
                    neptuneBatches.Where(
                        b => b.Items.Any(
                            i => i.ItemOrganisations.Any(
                                s => s.Issues.Any(
                                    x => x.Code == filter.IssueNo))));
```

Comment: That seems fine to me since you need to go 4 layers deep anyways.

Comment: Seconded.  I don't think you're going to find anything better than what you've got.